# Bootcamp/Win 7: No device drivers were found

Tags: bootcamp, windows

Man, installing bootcamp on my late 2013 15" Retina MBP is a challenge!

I was struggling for a very long time with the issue of not having any control og mouse/keyboard when entering the windows installer. On the apple forums there were all kinds of advices, from redownloading the drivers to using specific USB ports, but what I eventually found to be helping me was this tip which I think mounts the drive in "legacy mode" or something like that:

http://twocanoes.com/winclone/support#faq123

Now I can control mouse and keyboard, but soon after the installer tells me that "No device drivers were found. Make sure that the installation media contains the correct drivers and then click OK".

I am using a USB hd which I have formattet to be an install disk with drivers and everything from the bootcamp installer. Additionally I tried downloading these drivers:

http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1721

...and putting them on a USB pen-driver, but nevertheless, the windows installer can't see them and I can't get past this step. When I try to browse for the drivers I see two drives:

- BOOTCAMP (C:)
- BOOT (X:)

  - Program Files
  - sources
  - Users
  - Windows

(C:) is my bootcamp partition and I am assuming that (X:) is my install drive, but the file structure looks nothing like what it looks like from Mac OS X?? And there seems to be no drivers in any of these folders. Additionally, my USB pen-drive does not even show up.

I'm trying to install Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, btw. Tried the 32-bit version with same results.

How can I get the windows installer to recognize my device drivers?

Comment: So your question now is?

Comment: How do I get the installer to recognize my device drivers, so I can get on with the install?

Comment: Did you do that twocanoes thingy before the official KB?

Comment: KB? Yeah, if I don't run the terminal command suggested on twocanoes.com, I run into another very common problem which is that I can't use my mouse or keyboard in the windows installer. I run it after preparing my install disc, before booting into the win installer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you trying to follow [this kb (TS4599) by Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4599) and update the results in your question using an **Edit:** at the start of the edit.

I've posted the steps in the image below just to be certain you're reading the same as I've seen:

[image: steps as visible in TS4599]

Comment: Thanks, the key was to entirely remove the bootcamp partition and then add it again. After that both the issue with non-responsive mouse/keyboard and missing drivers disappeared :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked

Comment: I have the same problem, is it possible that this is caused because I use an USB 3.0 Device in my MBP Late 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same message and after trying multiple things that didn't work, I noted my Windows 7 disc wasn't clean. Windex solved the problem. Imagine that!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. What I ended up doing was copying the `$WinPEDriver$` and `BootCamp` folders from the USB stick to the root of the BootCamp partition. Make sure you copy and not move. When I booted the USB stick my keyboard and trackpad worked. I also no longer got the "drivers not found" error.

Comment: I followed your steps, and my keyboard and trackpad are not working in the windows installer

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem with the installation of Windows 8.1 Home 64 bit. After contacting Apple support several times and failing to resolve the problem, I contacted Microsoft. Their advice was to **try and find a PC with a similar architecture to the OS to be installed (in my case 64 bit)**:

- Format USB with NTFS protocol
- Use the Windows download tool to create a bootable USB on the PC.
- Download the latest Bootcamp support software from Apple, unzip it and copy files directly to USB root level (not inside another folder)
- Turn on Mac, insert USB and open Bootcamp assistant; **only check last option** (install Windows). **Do not check the other two options** ("Create a Windows ... install disk" and "Download support software from Apple") ***or Bootcamp will reformat the USB***!! You have already prepared the USB on the PC.
- Press continue, determine the size of the Windows partition you want and press continue. *Extra tip: I never divide by half, because during Windows installation I'm never sure which is the partition I need to use; they both appear to have same size and if I get to pick the wrong one I could lose my Mac OS partition. Picking a different size, even by a small fraction, lets you recognize the correct partition*.
- Bootcamp assistant will partition your disk and restart the computer.
- Windows will boot from the USB device and will proceed with the installation with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with as many of you.

Here is my contribution to the forum.

First identify your Bootcamp version, according to it you should install the 64 or 32 bits win on your mac and the drivers version according to your model identifier of your mac.

Third, and the most important dowload the drivers in your USB, open Win and click on setud and ready.

I added all the forums which help me to solve it.

General forum
http://www.123myit.com/boot-camp-drivers/macbook-pro/

Dowload Drivers Win 7 32bit (if they are missing when opening Win)
https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1635?viewlocale=pt_BR&locale=pt_BR

Regards,
Marcos Torres