# Late 2013 Macbook Retina Windows 7 x64 Bootcamp "No device drivers found"

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I have been trying for days to get Windows 7, 64 bit installed on my late 2013 Macbook Retina using bootcamp and always run into the same problem - when the Windows installation starts it gives an error message saying "No device drivers were found for my CD/DVD device..." and prompts be to try to browse to a location to find the drivers.

When I try to browse for the drivers I see two drives:

- BOOTCAMP (C:)
- BOOT (X:)

  - Program Files
  - sources
  - Users
  - Windows

(C:) is my bootcamp partition and I am assuming that (X:) is my install drive, but the file structure looks nothing like what it looks like from Mac OS X.

I never get the prompt asking me which partition to install Windows on.

I am using a USB drive and a Windows 7 64 bit ISO with Bootcamp Assistant. Everything goes smoothly in BCA. I have tried several different ISOs including one recommendation to use a specific ISO that is supposed to be a "full" version which includes additional drivers, but still with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (fixed) Pre-Installation Environment (boot.wim) of your Windows_7.iso doesn't contain the necessary drivers to use the USB3-interface of your `Late 2013 Macbook Retina`. So a "non-standard Windows7.iso" including "additional  drivers" without injecting/implementing them into the boot.wim won't help much either.
Btw `BOOT (X:)` is **not** your install drive but the mounted [boot.wim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Imaging_Format).

To circumvent limitations (new drivers, new hardware) Microsoft uses the $WinPEDriver$-feature to provide drivers at installation time.

Apple Boot Camp uses this method to provide the necessary drivers with the boot medium - your external USB drive.

Please check if you meet the following requirements:

1. Backup of your entire hard disc
2. <strike>Windows 7.iso [Home Premium x64](http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65733/X15-65733.iso), [Professional x64](http://msft-dnl.digitalrivercontent.net/msvista/pub/X15-65805/X15-65805.iso), or [Ultimate x64](https://drcdn.blob.core.windows.net/office2010/X15-65922.iso)
   (these three are us-en digitalriver isos and here is a full [list](http://www.heidoc.net/joomla/technology-science/microsoft/14-windows-7-direct-download-links) of all images available there).</strike> Please use [Microsoft Software Recovery](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery) to download the proper Winodws 7 release.
3. Formatting of the USB-device (according to Apple):

   If the size of the disk is 32 GB or less it should be MS-DOS (FAT).

   If the size of the disk is over 32 GB it should be ExFAT.

   Try to use an USB thumb drive (size 8 GB or bigger). If you don't have a thumb drive, try to use an USB hard drive smaller than 2 TB. ExFAT formatting with  Apple `disk utility.app` often doesn't work (means: formatting ends in FAT32 instead of ExFAT) and according to different [sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) a volume size limit of 2TB exists for MS-DOS (FAT) (=FAT32).
4. Boot Camp Support Software version: 5.1.5640

   download link: [Latest Boot Camp Support Software](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1721/en_US/BootCamp5.1.5640.zip)
5. File/Folder structure of the root of your boot device (your external USB-drive):

[image: root files and folders]

6. If your boot device doesn't contain `$WinPEDriver$`, `AutoUnattend.xml` and `BootCamp` please download and extract `BootCamp5.1.5640.zip` and copy the contents of the resulting `BootCamp` folder to the root level of your install drive.
7. If your install drive already contains those files and folders then check if the USB drivers are present.
   (Paths: /$WinPEDriver$/IntelxHCISetup/Drivers/HCSwitch/Win7/x64/ and /$WinPEDriver$/IntelxHCISetup/Drivers/xHCI/Win7/x64/).
   If they aren't present the wrong Boot Camp Support Software package has been chosen. Delete `$WinPEDriver$`, `AutoUnattend.xml` and `BootCamp` and continue with step 6.

Now the installation should work.

If the installation still doesn't work a more time consuming way has to be chosen (modifying the boot.vim) and i will write a second answer.

P.S. Did you already check this [apple.stackexchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/131108/bootcamp-win-7-no-device-drivers-were-found?rq=1) question/solution? Especially the comment of user `funkylaundry May 18 at 16:38`to the 1st answer:
"the key was to entirely remove the bootcamp partition and then add it again"

Comment: Wow, thanks. I will try this out when I get home from work. I saw that link you mentioned before but it didn't really seem applicable (I don't have an optical drive).

Comment: Wow indeed +10 on that. Where have you been all this time, we need more answers like this one :)

Comment: so did it work?

Comment: Worked. The only thing I did different was use a different (never used, 32GB) USB drive. Now there's just the issue of not being being able to swap the fn and ctrl keys under bootcamp...

Comment: @mclaassen http://blueskyworkshop.blogspot.de/2011/05/swap-control-and-command-keys-on.html?m=1

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to switch the fn key (not the command key)  http://superuser.com/questions/422750/how-to-swap-ctrl-and-fn-key-on-a-macbook-pro-running-windows-7-via-boot-camp

Comment: These ISO links are dead now

Comment: @MetalGear Added different link. Thanx for your hint.

Comment: @klanomath I want use key which came with my dell laptop and with that key "Microsoft Software Recovery" page is suggest to contact to dell for windows dvd.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer and instructions.  Unfortunately it's still not working for me. I followed all the instructions. I have the same kind of Mac. I'm still getting the 'no device drivers found' error.  Do I need to copy the drivers to the Windows directory, and then browse to them during the Windows install? That was suggested somewhere else.