# I can't install or remove windows 7 or later using Boot Camp Assistant?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I tried for a couple days to install Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro which has OSX Yosemite (10.10.2). 
As you see in the capture, the third checkbox is disabled. 
I have created a Windows 7 Install disk on a USB flash and downloaded the latest Windows support software from Apple, all I have to do is install it on the Mac.

What's the problem here?

[image]

---

## EDIT:

## ADDED THIS INFORMTION FOR [DAVID ANDERSON'S ANSWER](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171509/i-cant-install-or-remove-windows-7-or-later-using-boot-camp-assistance/171700#171700).

1. I checked the latest firmware, every thing was OK except Boot ROM Version, mine was( MBP101.00EE.B**07**), I tried to update it but the last number was different [MBP101.00EE.B**02**](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1591)
2. Model Identifier: **MacBookPro10,1**
3. Last night I Removed every thing on my Mac and then I used the Internet recovery for installing the OS again, It was successful.
4. My internet is not very bad, 600KB/s, and the boot was fast.
5. I did backups using TimeMachine, and also created image using Disk Utility.
6. I have a USB connected, I can write/read because it's formatted **MS-DOS(FAT)**.
7. Before I buy this Mac, I had a PC running Windows 7. I have 8 years experience in Windows, but I'm totally new to Mac OS.

## And for the Out put of the commands, here it is:

```
Last login: Fri Feb 13 13:36:10 on ttys000
Azads-MBP:~ Azad$ diskutil list
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *751.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS WINDOWS                 100.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS MAC DATA 1              325.5 GB   disk0s3
   4:          Apple_CoreStorage                         324.7 GB   disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS MAC OS                 *324.3 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s4
                                 XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
                                 Unencrypted
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *31.2 GB    disk2
   1:                 DOS_FAT_32 WININSTALL              31.2 GB    disk2s1
/dev/disk3
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *126.7 MB   disk3
   1:        Apple_partition_map                         30.7 KB    disk3s1
   2:         Apple_Driver_ATAPI                         2.0 KB     disk3s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS MacBook Pro Retina E... 126.7 MB   disk3s3


Azads-MBP:~ Azad$ diskutil cs list
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
    =========================================================
    Name:         MAC OS
    Status:       Online
    Size:         324682784768 B (324.7 GB)
    Free Space:   18882560 B (18.9 MB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s4
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     324682784768 B (324.7 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk1
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          324311580672 B (324.3 GB)
            Conversion Progress:   -none-
            Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
            LV Name:               MAC OS
            Volume Name:           MAC OS
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS



Azads-MBP:~ Azad$ sudo gpt -r -vvv show -l /dev/disk0
Password:
gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=751277983744; sectorsize=512; blocks=1467339812
gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, start=40, size=409600
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, start=409640, size=195312496
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, start=195984280, size=635677744
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, start=831924168, size=634146064
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX, start=1466070232, size=1269544
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 1467339811
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - "EFI System Partition"
      409640   195312496      2  GPT part - "WINDOWS"
   195722136      262144         
   195984280   635677744      3  GPT part - "MAC DATA 1"
   831662024      262144         
   831924168   634146064      4  GPT part - "MAC OS"
  1466070232     1269544      5  GPT part - "Recovery HD"
  1467339776           3         
  1467339779          32         Sec GPT table
  1467339811           1         Sec GPT header



Azads-MBP:~ Azad$ sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 91337/255/63 [1467339812 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [         1 - 1467339811] <Unknown ID>
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused      
Azads-MBP:~ Azad$
```

Comment: Are you using an .ISO image of a genuine Win 7 disc to create the USB installer? If so you shouldn't experience any issues. The bottom checkbox will be greyed-out unless the Boot Camp installer detects a valid disc or USB installer.

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly: I downloaded the .ISO from internet but not from the official website. Shall I have to download it there? Does this made this problem ?

Comment: If you downloaded it from "the internet" you may need to download a few different "versions" until you find one that works. An official one from MS will work. Assuming you have a Mac without an optical drive, if you have any friends with a retail version DVD you could ask them to create an .ISO from it using something like ImgBurn (PC, free).

Comment: Do you first get the following popup message? "**The startup disk cannot be partitioned or restored to a single partition.** The startup disk must be formatted as a single Mac OS Extended (Journaled) volume or already partitioned by Boot Camp Assistant for installing Windows."

Comment: @DavidAnderson: YES, this popup appears. It's written like this: *Format* **:Encrypted Logical Partition** . So what I shall do about that. I'm totally new to Mac.

Comment: @ScunnerDarkly: This version of .ISO that I have I installed it for several PCs, and I will buy a DVD and burn like you said.

Comment: This output I requested, did you create it before or after installing OS X? Also, I see all the UUID's as XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX. Did you do this? By the way, I do not care about the 100 reps. I would recommend any advice given by @klanomath. He is quite good.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: I felt like there is no need to show these numbers. and the question didn't have many attention that's why I gave 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to install or remove Windows7/8 with Boot Camp Assistant because you have a non-standard partition layout and the file system of your Windows partition is wrong (HFS+!):

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *751.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS WINDOWS                 100.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS MAC DATA 1              325.5 GB   disk0s3
   4:          Apple_CoreStorage                         324.7 GB   disk0s4
   5:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s5
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS MAC OS                 *324.3 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s4
                                 XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
                                 Unencrypted
```

A standard pre-Boot Camp (**CoreStorage**) partition layout looks like this:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *751.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         749.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS MAC OS                 *749.4 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
                                 Unencrypted
```

A standard pre-Boot Camp (**non-CoreStorage**) partition layout looks like this:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *751.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            750.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

The hybrid MBR/GUID necessary for Boot Camp Assistant to install/boot Windows doesn't allow more than 4 partitions:

- Apple CoreStorage or Macintosh HD
- Recovery HD
- your future Windows 7/8
- a place holder in the MBR (some count the EFI-partition as the fourth one, but this doesn't seem to be true)

A standard post-Boot Camp Assistant Win Install (**CoreStorage**) partition layout looks like this:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *751.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         324.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows                 425.1 GB   disk0s4                         
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS MAC OS                 *324.3 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
                                 Unencrypted
```

A standard post-Boot Camp Assistant Win Install (**non-CoreStorage**) partition layout looks like this:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *751.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            324.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data Windows                 425.1 GB   disk0s4
```

- So back up all necessary data on the volumes MAC DATA 1, MAC OS and WINDOWS to an external drive.
- Detach all external drives
- Reboot to Internet Recovery Mode (press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> after the start chime) which may take between 6 minutes (50 MBit/s) and up to an hour (5 MBit/s).
- Start Disk Utility and erase/partition the whole internal disk (GUID-partition scheme/HFS+/1 Partition). If you get an error message trying to erase your main drive, you might have to remove the CoreStorage volume first:

  - Booted to Internet Recovery Mode open Utilities → Terminal in the menubar and enter:
    `diskutil cs list` to get the CoreStorage listing.
  - Copy the Logical Volume UUID, it's the fourth listed.
  - Now delete the Logical Volume with `diskutil cs deleteVolume LVUUID`.
  - Copy the Logical Volume Group UUID, it's the first listed in the listing of `diskutil cs list`.
  - Then delete the Logical Volume Group with `diskutil cs delete LVGUUID`.
- Restore/reinstall Mac OS X.
- Upgrade to your preferred Mac OS X.
- Restore your backup data (but don't restore your old partition layout!). I recommend the Migration Assistant to import your system settings, applications and your user data.
- Start Boot Camp Assistant and install Windows7. If you run into problems (error message: "No device drivers were found for my CD/DVD device...") check my answer [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148246/late-2013-macbook-retina-windows-7-x64-bootcamp-no-device-drivers-found/148898#148898).

Comment: If you read his post, you will notice he reloaded OS X from the internet. I am not sure if the output he presented came before or after the reload.

Comment: I'v erased the entire disk, there only two titles remain **751.28 GB APPLE SSD SM768E Media**  and  **disk1--> Mac OS X Base System**. What to do next Please?

Comment: @klanomath: There no HFS, only Max OS Extended(Journaled) exists. and I selected the GUID too. 
What to do about HFS?

Comment: @klanomath: I did that, now I should back to the **Reinstall OS X** from the options?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21117/discussion-between-azad-and-klanomath).

Answer (score 1):

Right, now we have more information to go on, go to **Applications > Utilities > Disk Utility**. On the left pane you will see a list of storage devices, your boot drive should be at the top of the list. You should see the top device broken down into partitions. Highlight the "parent" drive (top of the list) and then click on **Partition**. In the main area you will see the drive partitions. Highlight the one you need to remove and click on the "-" button. This will prompt you to confirm removal of the partition. Once you've removed the partition you can then run Boot Camp Assistant and it should hopefully work ok.

Comment: @DavidAnderson: this is a head ache for me, I'm trying for 7 days without any result. I have two partitions **Apple** and **Data**, I want to delete the *Data* but it can't be deleted.

Comment: How do you know which partition @Azad should remove? I would have offered something less destructive than deleting partitions. I asked about the popup, because my Boot Camp Assistant also has the "Install or remove Windows 7 or later version" check box grayed out. I currently have OS X 10.10.2 and Windows 8.1 installed on my iMac.

Comment: @David Anderson, Disk Utility won't allow you to remove the currently booted OS X partition. Given Azad can only see two partitions, the only partition he will be able to remove is the one he is trying to remove.

Answer (score 1):

First off, create a partition called BOOTCAMP as Fat32 or ExFat - then shut down and plug in the Windows USB/CD

Turn on Mac and before it boots, hold down the `option` key. if the trackpad and/or keyboard doesn't work, plug in an external one.
Install Windows as Normal, while choosing the BOOTCAMP Drive as the destination partition.

visit this [site](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1721) and download the Bootcamp drivers. **Be sure to check your Mac Specifications!** They can be found at the bottom of the page.

Follow instructions to install the drivers - Done!

These are the same steps I had to use when the bootcamp assistant crapped on me like yours did.

Comment: How can I format the partition as NTFS, this type is exist only on Windows I think?!

Comment: oh! sorry I meant Fat32 or ExFat

Answer (score 1):

another possibility is that your firevault is encrypting or the encryption is on.
you need to turn off firevault off, then run the bootcamp.

Answer (score 0):

OK,

To start off, I will ask the typical questions.

Do you have the latest firmware for you Mac? See [EFI and SMC firmware updates for Intel-based Macs](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201518).

What is the Model Identifier of your Mac?

Can you edit your question and add the output from the following commands? To enter the commands, you will need to open a Terminal application window. Some of the commands will ask for your login password. This is normal. None of the commands change your Mac. They just give me more information.

```
diskutil list
diskutil cs list
sudo gpt -r -vvv show -l /dev/disk0
sudo fdisk /dev/disk0
```

It would be helpful to know your internet connection speed. Can you start your Mac using OS X Internet Recovery and report to me how long this takes? The instructions can be found at [OS X: About OS X Recovery](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718). I just what to know how long it takes to boot.

Do you do backups? If so how? For example, do you use Time Machine?

Do you have any flash drives for external disks available? If so, how are they partitioned and formatted.

Do you have other machines running Windows or OS X. If so, which versions?

Comment: I updated my question, please review it please.