# Making an installable ISO of Bootcamp drive

Tags: macos, backup, windows, install, iso

I have the 2016 MBP and built up my Windows 10 installation just as I would like it. To speed up recovery and re-installation to it's current point I would like to backup the Bootcamp drive so that I can reinstall from that and not have to reinstall Windows and all the applications I have now configured.

As a first attempt at this I installed DataNumen Disk Image and MacDrive 10 Standard. I used this combination to create a .img backup of the Bootcamp drive, from within Windows, to an external HFS+ formatted drive, so that if Windows fails I can still access the .img file from macOS Sierra.

Am I doing this correctly? Will I be able to reinstall from the .img file and short-circuit the painfully slow re-install process of Windows' apps? Is there a more appropriate method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would never attempt to handle any aspect of Boot Camp partitioning or data structuring from inside Windows.
Windows has no idea its partition is balanced precariously on a 'fake' MBR disk sitting inside a GUID partition. Too many people touch it & break it.

Instead I would use something designed specifically for Boot Camp installations within the Mac environment. That way you're not tightrope-walking.

As far as I'm aware, [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/) is the only app that can do the task in its entirety, handling Boot Camp & Mac partitions - move, backup/restore etc.

[TwoCanoe's WinClone](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone) can do the Boot Camp partition, but doesn't handle the Mac partitions.

[Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) is great for your Mac Partitions, but not Boot Camp. It requires you already have the specialised partitioning structure in place - see Bombich KB: [Can CCC back up my BootCamp (Windows) partition?](https://bombich.com/kb/ccc4/can-ccc-back-up-my-bootcamp-windows-partition)

<sup>I own all three, but am not affiliated with any of the recommendations</sup>

Comment: You're really getting at the main concern here: "Should the install be handled by Windows (I agree that it should not) and can an installable backup be made from the Mac side?" I will take a look at Paragon HDM. I was wondering if there are free/self-implemented answers (even if they are more involved.) Thank you.

Comment: There are a couple of guys on here who could pretty much *knit* you a hard drive if you gave them the wool ;-) One that springs immediately to mind is [klanomath](http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath) though there are others. Have a look at a couple of fairly random answers I picked out & see how scary it all looks... then buy the software ;) [cont'd...]

Comment: ...cont'd] http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171509/i-cant-install-or-remove-windows-7-or-later-using-boot-camp-assistant/171795#171795 and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/175483/how-do-i-regain-unaccessible-free-space-after-a-failed-boot-camp-install-on-a-no/175501#175501 ought to be enough to frighten anyone.